# How to make scons to write the target of a build in the build directory?

Tags: scons

I am trying to build a static library with Scons.
All I want to do is to build the object files and the library file in a build directory called "build-release".

Using VariantDir I can make scons build the object files in the build-release directory, but the libStringUtilities.a is still being wrote in the current directory, Why?

please, Any help will be wellcome.

My folder layout is the following.

```
MyLib/
  \--- project/
          \---- SConstruct
          \---- SConscript
  \--- src ( source files )
  \--- build-release ( build directory)
```

Here are my Sconscript ...

```
  Import('env')

  source_files = Glob('../build-release/*.cc')
  object_files = env.Object(source_files)
  env.StaticLibrary('StringUtilities',object_files)
```

...and Sconstruct files.

```
  import os

  env = Environment ( ENV = os.environ )

  Export('env')

  VariantDir('../build-release','../src',duplicate= False)
  SConscript('SConscript')
```

Answer (score 0):

Without trying this myself, try making your SConstruct file look like this?

```
import os

env = Environment ( ENV = os.environ )

env.VariantDir('../build-release', '../src',duplicate= False)
env.SConscript('SConscript', 'env')
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the intended folder structure when using scons (sconstruct in top level folder, and sconscripts in subfolders), but I think the problem is that you are building the library in the source folder. That is why it ends up there.

Try with:

```
env.StaticLibrary('../build-release/StringUtilities',object_files)
```